# Correctly traverse XML with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

First project with XSLT so I am still figuring it out but here I am trying to make sure I am only looking at Legal Name in this XML:

```
        <ws:Personal>
            <ws:Name_Data>
                <ws:Name_Type>Legal</ws:Name_Type>
                <ws:First_Name>Joana</ws:First_Name>
                <ws:Last_Name>Doe</ws:Last_Name>
            </ws:Name_Data>
            <ws:Name_Data>
                <ws:Name_Type>Preferred</ws:Name_Type>
                <ws:First_Name>Gabby</ws:First_Name>
                <ws:Last_Name>Doe</ws:Last_Name>
            </ws:Name_Data>
        </ws:Personal>
```

In my XSL I tried this which seems to work but I think there is a better way to go about it:

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:if test="ws:Name_Type='Legal'">
    ...do work
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

So how would I go about doing this if my desired output is 'Joana':

```
<xsl:value-of select="ws:Personal/ws:Name_Data/ws:First_Name"/>
```

When I have to only pull Name_Type Legal?

Comment: It would help to show your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve only the `ws:First_Name` element's values which are in the same `ws:Name_Data` parent elements having themselves a child named `ws:Name_Type` with the value "Legal", you can use a predicate on your expression like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ws:Personal/ws:Name_Data[ws:Name_Type='Legal']/ws:First_Name" />
```

**Output is:**

> Joana